# Get all user data with custom field drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal.  How do I get *all* user data in a single query or function, including extra fields like middle name, phone # from:

**Configuration » People » Account settings**

I want *all* the records of *all* the users, including the extra fields listed above.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are attached to the user : user_load();

Something like :
$user = user_load(1); // 1 = uid of admin user
drupal_set_message($user->field_middle_name); // print a message with your user custom field named middle_name.

If you got many users to load, use user_load_multiple, the perfs will be better.